# Custom marker icons (by category) for Google Maps for EE

Tags: google-maps-for-ee

EE v2.5.5
Google Maps Addon v3.2.2

I'm currently building a site that shows companies on a map. A requirement is to display custom POI icons per each entry's category.

Since the exp:gmap:marker tag pair sets the POI icon via the "icon" parameter, I don't have any way to pass in the entry category data.

**Is there a different or better way to render these POIs that gives me custom icon abilities?**

I'm currently using exp:gmap:results because the results page is displayed as a response to an address/location search with search radius specified.

Comment: Just FYI, I am still trying to figure out a way to do this with out using another add-on. How are you storing the marker icons paths for the categories? Could you store a path in a category field? Or at least the name of the icon and just prefix the relative path. Would that work? That's how most people do it.

Comment: Yeah, my plan is to either make use of the category_url_title and use that as a component of the filename or something similar.

Comment: Ok this helps. I think I will be able to get an example put together for this purpose. It should be easy enough since your rules are pretty simple and straight forward.

Comment: Justin, any chance of an update on this?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the solution involves using the latest version of Google Maps for ExpressionEngine and then using match_no_categories="true" as well as match_categories="true" on the exp:gmap:results tag pair.

This allows the use of {category_ids} for example in building a path to your icon images in the exp:gmap:marker icon parameter.